# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate doesn't return errors but also doesn't update the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use findOneAndUpdate() but can't seem to get it to work. Here's the query I'm using. It adds an object to an 'items' array nested inside of a 'lists' array for a particular entry with 'username'. I've tried it with a simple $set for a field not inside of a nested array, and it also doesn't seem to work. Currently no errors are being returned.

```
MongoClient.connect(
      uri,
      { useUnifiedTopology: true },
      (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("Todolist");
        dbo.collection("Users").findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            username: username,
            lists: {
              $elemMatch: {
                name: listName,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $push: {
              "lists.$.items": {
                title: title,
                description: description,
                dueDate: dueDate,
                priority: priority,
                completed: false,
              },
            },
          }
        );
      },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) res.send("/addListItem failed");
        else res.send("/addListItem successful");
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

Comment: maybe listName is not matching? have you tried a simple find query

Comment: What is the response? Share the sample data model data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.dot` notation along with the `$` positional operator here

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate(
  { username: username },
  { "lists.$.name": listName }
)
```

Comment: Also your lists should be array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the answer to my problem was bracket placement. I placed the callback after the closing `)` for the function arguments to `findOneAndUpdate`.